# Glimpse object null reference error with mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, glimpse

In visual studio with  "Break on Exceptions" turned on,  I see the following exception being raised (Object reference is null) - see below for call stack.

This occurs before my controller method is hit. Any ideas why this is happening?

I am using Asp.net mvc3 and version 0.87.0.0 of glimpse.mvc3.

> Glimpse.Core.DLL!Glimpse.Core.Extensions.HttpContextBaseExtensions.GetGlimpseRequestId(System.Web.HttpContextBase context = {System.Web.HttpContextWrapper}) + 0x55 bytes
>       Glimpse.Core.DLL!Glimpse.Core.Module.BeginRequest(System.Web.HttpContextBase context = {System.Web.HttpContextWrapper}) + 0xad bytes
>       Glimpse.Core.DLL!Glimpse.Core.Module.OnBeginRequest(object sender = {ASP.global_asax}, System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) + 0x7e bytes
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() + 0x95 bytes
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep step = {System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep}, ref bool completedSynchronously = false) + 0x4c bytes
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(System.Exception error) + 0x39f bytes 
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(System.Web.HttpContext context, System.AsyncCallback cb) + 0x5a bytes 
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest wr = {System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest}, System.Web.HttpContext context = {System.Web.HttpContext}) + 0xbe bytes
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(System.IntPtr managedHttpContext, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext = 543781828, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags) + 0x247 bytes 
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(System.IntPtr managedHttpContext, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags) + 0x29 bytes

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I see it to in Intellitrace in vs2011 beta as well; I dont worry about it :o) I think you can stop it by going to http://localhost/glimpse.axd and turning glimpse on. That sets the cookie and the id is found. no exception...

That is my guess anyway..

Cheers,
O